# Clang rejects while gcc accepts new C[ ]{1}

Tags: c++

I've written the following program that uses `new`. But the problem is that clang rejects the program while gcc and msvc accepts it. My question is which compiler is right here?

```
struct C{
   C(int);
};
int main() {
    C *ptr{new C[]{1}}; //clang rejects but gcc accepts
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/hzxfdnzod)

Clang says:

```
<source>:6:21: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'C'
    6 |     C *ptr{new C[]{1}}; //clang rejects but gcc accepts
      |                     ^
<source>:3:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    3 |    C(int);
      |    ^ ~~~
<source>:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    2 | struct C{
      |        ^
<source>:2:8: note: candidat
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/E5zocsM9d

Comment: What version of Clang are you using? How are you building, what options and flags are you providing? Are you on a macOS system and using the default Clang installation?

Comment: This is [p1009r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf). Looks like a clang bug to me.

Comment: [Array size deduction in new-expressions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf) and was supposedly implemented in clang 9 according to [compiler support @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) - but that doesn't work in clang 9 either so the table must be wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, I noticed that too. Will file a clang bug shortly.

Comment: This is interesting it works for `int` type: https://godbolt.org/z/PxW1bK6Pa

Answer (score 5):

This is [p1009r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf) and the program is **well-formed** and it is a [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/81157).

Basically, **array size**(when using with `new`) **can now be deduced from the number of elements in the braced init list**.

From [Array size deduction in new expressions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf):

| C++17 | This proposal |
| --- | --- |
| `double* p = new double[]{1,2,3};` // Error | `double* p = new double[]{1,2,3};` // OK |

---

So clang is wrong in giving a diagnostic here.

Here is the confirmed clang bug report:

[Clang rejects valid program having `new C[]{1}`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/81157)

Comment: works for `int`-s https://godbolt.org/z/PxW1bK6Pa

Comment: @MarekR Yeah, strange. Here is the filed bug: [Clang rejects valid program having new C[\]{1}](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/81157)

Comment: [better demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1WfP9f7jM)